# SharePoint get field value as text

Tags: splistitem, object-model, spfield

For JSOM we have a great method called **get_fieldValuesAsText** that returns formatted field value. The same value as user can see it in the list.
I am really supprised that I can't find anything like this on the native Sharepoint object model! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint object model also has a nifty way of getting all the values. [GetDataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection.getdatatable.aspx) method returns a data table with all the field values.

**Update:**

To return all fields as string, you can clone the DataTable and get string values in another DataTable.

```
DataTable dt = list.GetItems(new SPQuery()).GetDataTable();
DataTable dtClone = dt.Clone(); //just copy structure, no data
for (int i = 0; i < dtClone.Columns.Count; i++)
{
if (dtClone.Columns[i].DataType != typeof(string))
    dtClone.Columns[i].DataType = typeof(string);
}
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
dtClone.ImportRow(dr);
}
```

Comment: itemRow["Modified"] still returns DateTime object

Comment: @Serhiy modified code. Please check if it suits your requirement.

Comment: cant you get the values using item["FieldName"] and then convert it as per your need, as far as I know there isn't any such method as you stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Available also in **CSOM**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.fieldvaluesastext.aspx

And **REST**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItemProperties

As far as I can tell, not available in **SSOM**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem_properties.aspx